# Dynamic Calculated Column on different report level SSAS DAX query

Tags: dax, ssas, ssas-tabular, daxstudio

I'm trying to create a calculated column based on a derived measure in SSAS cube, this measure which will count the number of cases per order so for one order if it has 3 cases it will have the value 3.

Now I'm trying to create a bucket attribute which says 1caseOrder,2caseOrder,3caseOrder,3+caseOrder. I tried the below one

> IF([nrofcase] = 1, "nrofcase[1]", IF([nrofcase] = 2, "nrofcase[2]",
> IF([nrofcase] = 3, "nrofcase[3]", "nrofcase[>3]") )

But it doesn't work as expected, when the level of the report is changed from qtr to week it was suppose to recalculate on different level.

Please let me know if it case work.

Comment: You can't have dynamically calculated columns based on a measure, you'll need to us an X measure to achieve the same affect SUMX for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculated columns are static. When the column is added and when the table is processed, the value is calculated and stored. The only way for the value to change is to reprocess the model. If the formula refers to a DAX measure, it will use the measure without any of the context from the report (eg. no row filters or slicers, etc.).

Think of it this way:

- Calculated column is a fact about a row that doesn't change. It is known just by looking at a single row. An example of this is Cost = [Quantity] * [Unit Price]. Cost never changes and is known by looking at the Quantity and Unit Price columns. It doesn't matter what filters or context are in the report. Cost doesn't change.
- A measure is a fact about a table. You have to look at multiple rows to calculate its value. An example is Total Cost = SUM(Sales[Cost]). You want this value to change depending on the context of time, region, product, etc., so it's value is not stored but calculated dynamically in the report.

It sounds like for your data, there are multiple rows that tell you the number of cases per order, so this is a measure. Use a measure instead of a calculated column.